# Result of each condition in "or" while doing update operation in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, collections

```
Collection Name:- col
{ 
_id : ObjectId(".....1")
sid : "100"
name: "aaaa"
activity: "open"
}

{
_id : ObjectId(".....2")
sid : "100"
name: "bbbb"
activity: "open"
}

{
_id : ObjectId(".....3")
sid : "200"
name: "cccc"
activity: "close"
}
```

Suppose, I have to update the collection like this:-

```
db.col.update(
 {$or: [ {"sid" : "100"},
         {"sid" : "100"},   # Redundant
         {"sid" : "400"},   # Not in collection
         {"sid" : "100", "name" : "aaaa"}   # Redundant
      ]},
 {$set: {"activity": "close"}}, {multi: true}
)
```

This will return me WriteResult({"nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted": 0, "nModified": 2})

I want to get a result something like this:-

```
WriteResult({"nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted": 0, "nModified": 2})  # For 1st condition
WriteResult({"nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted": 0, "nModified": 0})  # For 2nd condition
WriteResult({"nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted": 0, "nModified": 0})  # For 3rd condition
WriteResult({"nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted": 0, "nModified": 0})  # For 4th condition
```

Can I get a result like this? I tried using aggregation pipeline after update but I was not able to get redundant condition result and "not in collection" condition result. Is there any way I can have a result something similar like the above one?

Comment: I can't get what you trying to do. Maybe an expected output?

Comment: Actually, I want to get 4 results instead of just one. I have queried for 4 conditions in "or" and therefore, I want to get 4 results. I am not saying that i want to get result while doing update operation. You can use any other operation after update also to get the similar result as mentioned above, like an aggregation pipeline or something like that. Also, use all 4 conditions together instead of separately updating or doing any such operations on the conditions.

Comment: The only option you have is to execute 4 different updates